# Elegantly Coding a try: except chain

Tags: python, loops, concurrent.futures

I have a in concurrent.futures that usually works with chunksize=1. However, occasionally I hit a large dataset that requires a larger chunksize. Currently I have solved this issue with the following code:

```
for i in datasets:
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results=tuple(executor.map(do_something, parameters, chunksize=1)
    except concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
        try:
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results=tuple(executor.map(do_something, parameters, chunksize=2)
        except concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
            try:
                with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                    results=tuple(executor.map(do_something, parameters, chunksize=4)
            etc. etc. etc....
            except concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
                   print('code failed')
```

This works fine, but is obviously really inelegant and ugly. Anyway that I can do this more simply?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate through the chunk sizes, `break` the loop if it succeeds, or enter an `else` block to output the error message:

```
for i in datasets:
    for chunksize in 1, 2, 4:
        try:
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results=tuple(executor.map(do_something, parameters, chunksize=chunksize)
            break
        except concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
            pass
    else:
        print('code failed')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another loop to accomplish this.  The code you're executing is the same every time with a different chunk size.  Here is an example using a `for` loop

```
for i in datasets:

    for chunksize in [1,2,4]:
      try:
          with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
              results=tuple(executor.map(do_something, parameters, chunksize=chunksize)
          break
      except concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool:
          if chunksize == 4:
            raise SomeErrorForMaxRetries
          else:
            continue
```

Comment: Do you need to create a new executor each time? I was thinking you can put `executor =concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` before the loop, and just use `with executor:` inside the loop.

Comment: You probably could but the OP was creating a new one each time so was sticking with that logic.

Comment: You can also use put the `raise SomeErrorForMaxRetries` in an `else` clause on the loop itself rather than check the current chunk size each time an exception is caught. The `else` clause only executes if `break` never successfully executed. (Like blhsing does, which I would have  noticed had I scrolled down sooner.)

Comment: Yes that is also doable but I see someone else already put that in their answer, no need to repeat it IMO, particularly for a stylistic change